# CSS. Link button from <span> tag

Tags: css

Sorry for noob question. I can't figure out how to create a link button.
I want that two `span` tags to be inline, but get one under another.

HTML

```
<span style="display: inline">
<span class="icon-cancel"></span>
<span>Cancel operation</span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.icon-cancel {
    display: block;
    background: no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
.icon-cancel {
    background-image: url("../img/ui/controls/cancel/cancel1.png");
}
```

Comment: `<span style="display: inline">` is redundant. `<span>` tags are already inline. Also, setting a `span` to be a `block` is abusing the `span`. `div` tags are `block` elements by default, so use them instead...

Comment: lol @ "abusing the span"

Comment: @Blender: I've seen you make this claim before that spans should not be styled with the `display` property, where are you getting this from (citation plz)?

Comment: No citation needed. `<span style="display: block;">` == `<div>`. `<span style="display: inline;">` == `<span>`. It's just the way the elements work.

Comment: They *can* be styled, but please don't style them in such a way so that they act *exactly* like another element, which is the case here.

Comment: @Blender: Reference is needed. Why are you pleading for people not to style elements to "act like other elements"? It just makes no sense, what is your purpose? Why are you claiming this is "abuse"?

Comment: It's plain logic: why emulate the behavior of another element by modifying a previous one? It's like putting an engine, four tires, a chassis, and a windshield onto a bicycle. Why not just get a car in the first place? They are virtually the same (exactly in the HTML sense).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner `<span>` (`.iconCancel`) is `display: block`.

You should make it `inline-block`, so that it is laid out as an inline element but treated as a block element.

Answer (score 0):

You need your friend, inline-block. Inline-block works for everything but IE 7 and prior. There is a hack to make it work for them too, which is the zoom and *display attributes, as seen below.

For this you apply it on the outside element. The styling for the insides looks good.

```
<span class="inlineblock">  
<span class="icon-cancel"></span>  
<span>Cancel operation</span>
</span>
```

And

```
 <style>
 .inlineblock{
     background:#ccc;
     display: inline-block;
     zoom: 1;
     *display: inline;
 } 
 </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<span>
<div class="cancel icon-cancel"></div>
<div class="cancel">Cancel operation</div>
</span>

.cancel {
    background: no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 16px;
    width:auto;
}
.icon-cancel {
    background-image: url("../img/ui/controls/cancel/cancel1.png");
    width: 16px;
}
```

Comment: You cannot nest block elements inside inline elements

Comment: You can. Just set `<span>` to be a `block` element and the `<div>`s to be `inline` ;)

Comment: @Blender: Won't validate, and you are contradicting your previous statements.

Comment: The smily face is denoting sarcasm. No, it does not validate, but the W3 validator says: *One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").* It's not allowing `block` within `inline`, but setting a stylesheet to swap the roles of both will be valid (from the validator's argument).